# how to make a Hazy/Cloudy like effect over certain SKSpriteNodes in SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I would like to create the hazy/cloudy like effect seen in the images below (the hazy effect seems to be working on everything apart from the game character in front) in a way that I can time the level of cloudiness using an action. I am interested in it affecting certain sprites, not all sprites.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, I'm not seeing any haziness. Do you mean the fact that the buttons have little shadows underneath them?

Comment: Look into `SKEffectNodes` and `CIFilters`

Comment: @Confused I added another image so you can see the difference

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for the advice. The filters are quite how can I find the exact one I need?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346

Comment: argh, I see what you're talking about. Graphically, this is known as a fade. The reason for this is that colour from behind (or in front) has been permitted to fade into the other graphics entities. In this case, it's a fade to white. Not all the way, but part of the way. The items that aren't fading to white are set above the fade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is creating a whole screen sized SpriteNode, that's filled with white. Place this over the top of all other nodes, except the nodes you don't want faded.

So if you have nodes A, B, C, D, E and F, and you want all but F to be faded, and the user's screen is to the right... like this:

A, B, C, D, E, [white layer], F  -> viewer/camera here.

The opacity of the white layer can't be 100% opaque, because if it is you won't see anything other than F and the white layer. So set the white layer to about (in this case) 33% opaque, via the SKSpriteNode's alpha value. 1 is fully opaque, 0.33 is 33% opaque, or 67% transparent ;)

One other tip, you can change the blend mode of nodes, for which Additive blend mode is the best for this , but normal will be good, too.